# Using image for UITableView background; background still shows black

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've got a grey custom image that I'm using as my background for a UITableView.  Image is PNG with the appropriate alpha settings, has rounded corners, and loads fine.  Despite using the following, however, I still see a black "background" where the corners become transparent.

[image]

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "someImage"))
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

I also set my TableView background to bright colors to see if that's where the issue was, however still black on the background.

[image]

How do I get this area to be completely transparent so it looks as if my round corners are the end of the TableView?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you displaying any cells on the tableview ?

Comment: try with setting `tableView.layer.cornerRadius`

Comment: @vivekDas yes, I am displaying cells however they are clear.

Comment: @Rocky unfortunately, three of the corners have the rounded aspect but I need one to be square so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet. Hope this works

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)  
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg")
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: It seems to only set the background black and removes the image I had setup.